# Scrollbar css works in Google chrome but not in mozilla and Internet Explorer

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Scrollbar css works in Google chrome but not in mozilla and Internet Explorer.
My css is

```
  .skin-1 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
             width: 5px;
      }    
     .skin-1 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
         background-color: #eaeaea;
         border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
      }    
     .skin-1 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #0e9aef;
      }    
    .skin-1 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background-color: #aaa;
    }
```

Comment: Please add also HTML code, or best working JSFiddle with minimal problem, so we can reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is exposed behind the `-webkit` vendor prefix for use in browsers using the Webkit (and Blink) rendering engine.

[image]

please read this [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/).

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar is NOT a css standard, that means some browsers may support it while others don't. In this case you are applying the `-webkit-´- prefix which aims just to next browsers:

> Android, Chrome, iOS and  Safari.

You can check [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm) for more info.

Aa long as I know scroll bar is not supported at all in Firefox (if not changed reciently).

for a full browser compatibility I would recomend You to use some nice (and easy to use) jquery libraries around.